# data not passing from model class in bindviewholder in use of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
Look on `onbindViewholder`, I used a model class that contains two texts but the model class not showing any of these.

I tried new model class and new project, but still, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the fact the name of the class is the same as the name of the argument that exists inside the `onBindViewHolder` method:

[image]

To solve this problem, you have to change the name of `firebaseModelClass` class to start with a capital letter:

```
public class FirebaseModelClass {
    //...
}
```

Classes in Java [always start with a capital letter](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?